# R for loop with file path character list only runs on first file

Tags: r, pdftools, tabulizer

I have a for loop in R and a character list including the pdf files I am trying to extract data from using the tabulizer package.

```
pdf_list <- list.files("/path")



for (i in 1:length(pdf_list)){
  extract_tables(paste(pdf_list[i])) ->df
  do.call(rbind, df[-length(df)]) -> final
  colnames(final) <- c("col1", "col2", "col3")

}
```

the loop works but only for the first pdf in the directory. I am rather new to loops in R and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What doesn't work after the first run?

Comment: Your paste is unnecessary.  Just use `extract_tables(pdf_list[i]) ->df`

Comment: Thanks for the information on the paste function. There are two PDFs in the PDF
_list object. The for loop only works on the first pdf however. is there a way to make this run through each pdf in the directory?

Comment: Check that length(pdf_list) returns the number of PDFs you expect it to. Then make sure that rbind is working correctly. If the dataframe's columns are not exactly the same rbind will not work. If this is the case, use rbind.fill.

Comment: Are you expecting to have multiple results? The loop will run once for each `i`, but you recreate `final` each time.

Comment: I'm not sure what the appropriate response is here. Some kind soul solved this issue with a combination of pdftools pdf_combine, and tabulizer's extract_tables. It looks like they've since deleted their comments. Whomever this was, I am thankful for your help.